# Arrange html element in circle with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, button, geometry

I have a set of 7 jQuery UI [buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/). Precisely speaking, Buttonset.

I want to arrange all buttons in a circle.
How can I arrange them in that fashion with CSS (CSS3 is out of game- seek a cross browser solution) and jQuery?

I have seen a few plugins:

1) [Roundrr](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-roundrr/)

2) [jsshapelib](http://github.com/addyosmani/js-shapelib)

and few demos [here](http://www.piccante.co/?pg=circularmenus)

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <button id="button-1" class="circle" >1</button>
    <button id="button-2" class="circle" >2</button>
    <button id="button-3" class="circle" >3</button>
    <button id="button-4" class="circle" >4</button>
    <button id="button-5" class="circle" >5</button>
    <button id="button-6" class="circle" >6</button>
    <button id="button-7" class="circle" >7</button>    
</div>
```

Looking for a jQuery solution to arrange all children of `#button-wrapper` in a circle within height and width of `#button-wrapper`.

Comment: So you have found at least two plugins and demos - why can't you use them?

Comment: if its acheivable with few lines of jquery why to use these plugins

Comment: If it's achievable with a few lines of jQuery, why post this question?

Answer (score 2):

You could position them with `position: absolute` (and `position: relative` on the centered button).
With some basic math you can calculate the `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`left` values.

```
cos(angle) = right/left value
sin(angle) = top/bottom value
```

Comment: its not difficult to find top and left value of absolutely positioned buttons ,i want to acheive a jquery solution to arrange all children of a parent container in a circle,like a function

Comment: @JaideepSingh, then what do you want?  You found two perfectly good plugins and now here's an answer with critical information towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is just mathematic. Create a Div with the size you want and with the position property set to relative.

Absolute position the center button, and either get it's size or calculate from the center of the div and absolute position the other buttons around it with regards to their and the middle buttons size so that they dont overlap eachother or atleast not more than you want.